# Does the axiom schema of collection imply schematic dependent choice in ZFCU?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let ${\sf ZFCU}$ be the axioms of ${\sf ZFC}$ modified to allow for urelements in the usual way. We do not assume that the urelements form a set.

I want to know whether ${\sf ZFCU}$ plus the axiom schema of collection---i.e.:

(Collection) $\forall x\exists y \phi(x, y) \to \forall z\exists w\forall x\in z\exists y\in w \phi(x, y)$

implies schematic dependent choice---i.e.:

(SDC) $\forall x\exists y\phi(x, y) \to \forall z\exists f(f(0) = z \wedge \forall n\phi(f(n), f(n+1)))$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't collection already part of $\mathsf{ZFCU}$, and for that matter SDC already a consequence of choice in $\mathsf{ZFU}$?

Comment: Didn't you ask this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337583/does-the-principle-of-schematic-dependent-choice-follow-from-zfcu?rq=1

Comment: @NoahSchweber See the question Asaf linked!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. Why? Unless I'm missing something (totally possible), the models you gave there don't model collection.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533971/is-set-sized-choice-over-proper-classes-weaker-than-global-choice works?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't see it yet (I had a somewhat similar idea but couldn't make it work). In the model you given global choice fails, but why will SDC fail?

Comment: (Ah, my previous comment is correct, so I re-state it) $\mathsf{SDC}$ is equivalent to the following statement: for every formula $\phi(x,y)$, if $\forall x\exists y \phi(x,y)$ then there is a set $A$ such that $\forall x\in A\exists y\in A \phi(x,y)$. The proof is almost identical to that of Theorem 2.4 of Aczel's *The Relation Reflection Scheme.* (But we need some modification for proving the above statement from $\mathsf{SDC}$.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Then I'll repost my reply! The equivalence is right, of course (given collection). But I don't see immediately how that helps.

Comment: @GME That's embarrassing - *I* posted an answer to that question too! :P

Comment: @NoahSchweber haha no worries! I've done worse; easily.

Comment: I think your $\mathsf{SDC}$ also implies the reflection principle (at least a partial form of it.) I think the results in [Section 4 of Blechschmidt and Swan](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/paper-reflection.pdf) works. (But I have not checked that how can reduce some $\mathsf{RRS}_2$ kinds of stuff to $\mathsf{SDC}$.)

Comment: (Or I may go too far: Lemma 11.1 of [Gitman-Friedman-Kanovei](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219061318500137?casa_token=H-_Z277C3BsAAAAA:JFA3uoQboGMlmPV8e6QWysv84mRNYxWdf8mPQpxBNDmpYkCkrUM3uxlcN7oEY63BWJM_REIISENz6Ix9) would work.)

Comment: Indeed, it does! In fact, I‘m interested in SDC /because/ it implies a particular reflection principle. What I want to know is whether collection could be used instead. (The reflection principle implies SDC). But again, I don‘t see how that helps.